# How to raise a variable to a power and store it to another variable

Tags: python, replit

Image of my code: [image]

I'm new to pyton and i'm trying to raise the input of the variable x and y to the second power, but i don't know how to. Plz help, this is due on friday :'-(

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: You even said this was homework.  You cannot ask us to do your homework for you.  That's unethical.  Note that ANY beginning Python tutorial would cover this question, as did your instructor in class.  `(x**+**y)` is C syntax, not Python.  The syntax for returning the square of `x` is `x**2`.

Comment: `x**` by itself is invalid syntax.  If you want x^2, you need to use `x**2`.  Similarly, I'm guessing `**y` should be `y**2`.

Comment: What are you actually trying to *do*? Compute the area of a rectangle? No exponentiation is required for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(input("The first side\'s length:"))
y = float(input("The second side\'s length:"))

z = x**2 + y**2
```

I assume you want Z to be the sum of x squared and y squared. Regardless, the correct syntax for squaring is using `**2`

Comment: Why are you assuming that?

Comment: By the nature of the attempted code? Looks like they might be trying to find the third side of a right triangle.